# getting error while working with array of object

Tags: java, eclipse, object

Can anyone tell how to make FogDevice fd[i] = (FogDevice) addFogDevice(str[i]); instead of  FogDevice fd= (FogDevice) addFogDevice(str[i]); What changes to make in the function definition also .

```
package org.fog.examples;


public class createdevice {
    static List<FogDevice> fogDevices = new ArrayList<FogDevice>();
    static List<String> Mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         File file = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/demo.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
             String st = sc.nextLine();
             Mylist.add(st);
         }
        String list[] = new String[Mylist.size()];
    
        Object[] obj = Mylist.toArray();
        String[] str = (String[]) Arrays.copyOf(obj,obj.length,String[].class); 
    
    
        for(int i =0; i< str.length-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("String is "+str[i]);
            FogDevice fd= (FogDevice) addFogDevice(str[i]);
        
          } 
        
    }

    private static FogDevice addFogDevice(String b) {
        String[] a = b.split(",");
        String name = a[0];
        boolean isCloud = Boolean.parseBoolean(a[1]);
        long mips = Long.parseLong(a[2]);
        int ram = Integer.parseInt(a[3]);
        Double ratepermips = Double.parseDouble(a[4]);
        Double busypower = Double.parseDouble(a[5]);
        Double idlepower = Double.parseDouble(a[6]);
    FogDeviceCharacteristics characteristics = new FogDeviceCharacteristics(isCloud, 
            arch, os, vmm, host, time_zone, cost, costPerMem,
            costPerStorage, costPerBw);

    FogDevice fogdevice = null;
    try {
        // TODO Check about scheduling interval
        fogdevice = new FogDevice(name, characteristics, 
                new AppModuleAllocationPolicy(hostList), storageList, 10, ratepermips);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fogdevice;
}
```

}

Is there anyway to store each str content to fogdevice object? i want to store each extracted line from the text file to array of fogdevice object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply initialize array of `FogDevice` and then use it in your loop like this:

```java
FogDevice fdArray[] = new FogDevice[str.length - 1]; // Initialize array 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("String is " + str[i]);
    fdArray[i] = addFogDevice(str[i]); // Assign value computed from str[i] -> fdArray[i]

}
```

**Update:**
From comments, it looks like you wanted your method to return array. You can easily create a method which you return a `FogDevice[]` based on an input `String[]`. Here is an example:

```java
    /**
     * Create an array of FogDevice objects
     *
     * @param str an array of strings
     * @return FogDevice[] array
     */
    private static FogDevice[] addFogDevices(String[] str) {
        FogDevice[] fdArray = new FogDevice[str.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
            // Delegate Single FogDevice creation to your old method;
            fdArray[i] = addFogDevice(str[i]);
        }
        return fdArray;
    }

    /**
     * Create FogDevice
     * @param inputStr provided string from which to extract details
     * @return FogDevice
     */
    private static FogDevice addFogDevice(String inputStr) {
        // ...
    }
```

Then in your `main()` method you can use it like this:

```java
FogDevice[] fogDevices = addFogDevices(str);
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your response. so this statement is required or not ?                                     
         static List<FogDevice> fogDevices = new ArrayList<FogDevice>()

Comment: This way you won't need to change method signature of `addFogDevice`. I added this since you asked in question for this: ` fd[i] = (FogDevice) addFogDevice(str[i]);`. `addFogDevice` seems to be handing only single `FogDevice` objects right now

Comment: yes how to make this to handle multiple objects at a time?